# Joomla install on Apache2 missing mods

Tags: apache2, joomla

I am running ubuntu 16.04.4 and installed the LAMP stack as part of the install process. I have managed to get Apache2, MySql, PHP to work after quite a struggle. I want to now install Joomla onto the webserver and all I get is the word 'Error' when I try to run the setup process on the Joomla install. After looking through the required spec for Joomla is says appache2 need to have mod_mysql, mod_xml, and mod_zlib. I've searched through all of the files and cant find any of these mod files. How can I get them? I've searched everywhere I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing php mods, these can be installed with

```
apt install php7.0-mysql php7.0-xml
```

once you install them, they should be enabled by default but if they aren't you can uncomment the appropriate lines in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini